# Python if, else statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I have started learning python on my own for fun and I was writing this and did not get the results i wanted:

```
if no1234 == 0:
     print "Player and Computer tie!\n"
elif no1234 == 1 or 2:
     print "Player wins!\n"
elif no1234 == 3 or 4:
     print "Computer wins!\n"
```

computer wins would not show up, is there something im forgetting

Answer (score 5):

`elif no1234 == 1 or 2:` is parsed as `elif (no1234 == 1) or (2):`

It will always be `True` because `bool(2) == True` and you're using an `or` statement.

You probably wanted:

```
elif no1234 == 1 or no1234 == 2:
```

Or even:

```
elif no1234 in (1, 2):
```

This is the same for your other `elif`.

---

So altogether:

```
if no1234 == 0:
     print "Player and Computer tie!\n"
elif no1234 in (1, 2):
     print "Player wins!\n"
elif no1234 in (3, 4):
     print "Computer wins!\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need this:

```
if no1234 == 0:
     print "Player and Computer tie!\n"
elif no1234 == 1 or no1234 == 2:
     print "Player wins!\n"
elif no1234 == 3 or no1234 == 4:
     print "Computer wins!\n"
```